# How do I turn off friendly error messages in IIS Express running on Chrome?

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, iis-express

I switch from Visual Studio 2013's Development Environment to IIS Express. My browser of choice is Chrome.

I used to get the standard ASP.net error page in D.E. but now I get a friendly error message page in IIS Express. How do I show detailed error messages in Chrome?

In case you're wondering, I know there's an error in my code. I did that on purpose to see how error message's display in IIS Express

[image]

How do I display detailed errors in Chrome?

[image]

Update: The error was caused by a malformed Web.Config. How do I set up IIS Express to display detailed Web.Config error message?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set  in the web.config file

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```